# Handling of a blockchain asynchronous operation in Ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, web3js

I am calling an angular service which implements an Ethereum `send` operation (a blockchain write) through Ngrx's effect.
The result of this `send` operation returns a transaction hash (a combined promise eventemitter) through which I can subscribe to in order to receive the actual data of my `send` operation.

I am wondering what is a good design for this situation.
This is

1. A Ngrx action dispatch (from my angular component) is a asynchronous (fire forget) operation.
2. My effect makes the transactional call to the Ethereum network and return a transaction hash, that is an instance of a combined promise-eventemitter.
3. The effect would encapsulate the returned promise (2) in an action that should be reduced, i.e. to be placed in the store so that it can be selected by the calling component (or other components).

There is one issue in the above approach:

The promise returned is not serialisable and can't be handled in a Ngrx store, that is it can not be put in the store and therefor some component can't subscribe to to receive the blockchain operation's result.

***Is there a design pattern in Angular/Ngrx to handle blockchain transactional operations (send())?***
(I use Web3 as my ethereum API.)

Comment: Why not let the effect handle the completion of the promise and then return an action with the result for the reducer?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Good suggestion. I was confused in the way a blockchain transaction (write) would be handled. I mixed up some issues with respect to waiting time. I assumed that I could wait a long time before the mining would be settled (minutes) and then I would get a response back (even as a promise).